# How can the mouse listener activate after a certain time when the mouse is already over the button?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, border, mouselistener

I'm trying to have a border appear over the react button after the timer has ended. I can't seem to have that happen unless I move the mouse away from the trigger button and then back onto it. Is there a way to activate the mouse listener without moving the mouse off and then back on the trigger button after the timer? And please dont't say: set border when timer ends, because that's not what I'm looking for.
Also, feel free to point out other mistakes or bad habits with my code as well. I'm new to Java coding.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class ButtonTester{

  public static final Border PANEL_BORDER = new LineBorder(Color.red, 12);
  public static JPanel panel;
  public static JButton trigger;
  public static JButton react;
  public static JLabel msg;

  public static void main(String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,200)); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(PANEL_BORDER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    JButton trigger = new JButton("Trigger");
    JButton react = new JButton("React");
    JLabel msg = new JLabel();
    react.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));
    trigger.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));

    panel.add(trigger); 
    panel.add(react);
    panel.add(msg);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    MouseListener mL = new MouseAdapter(){
      @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
        react.setBorder(PANEL_BORDER);
      }
      @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
        react.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      }
    };
    countDown(msg, trigger, mL);
  }

  public static void countDown(JLabel msg, JButton trigger, MouseListener mL){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
      short seconds = 4; 
      public void run(){
        if(seconds == 0){
          timer.cancel(); 
          trigger.addMouseListener(mL); 
          return;
        }
        seconds--;
        msg.setText("Attempting to add listener in : "+seconds);
      }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
  }

}
```

Comment: *"Also, feel free to point out other mistakes or bad habits with my code as well. I'm new to Java coding"* - Don't use `java.util.Timer` when you want to interact with the UI, use either a `SwingWorker` or `javax.swing.Timer`. I'd also avoid using `setPreferredSize`, it doesn't take into account many of the conditions which `getPreferredSize` uses to calculate it's value. Instead, considering using things like `setMargin` on `JButton` or different  layout constraints available in different layout managers

Comment: *"And please dont't say: set border when timer ends, because that's not what I'm looking for"* - ok, but that sounds exactly like what you're asking - *"I'm trying to have the react button appear with a border after the timer has ended"* ... so I'm confused

Comment: So, what you "seem" to be saying say is, if the mouse is over the `trigger` button AFTER you've set the `MouseAdapter` to it, you then want the listener to be triggered?  How about instead, you apply the listener up front, you can then have two flags, one which determines if the mouse has entered or exited the button and one which determines if the timer has been completed or not, this way, you can combine the two. It might require an additional method or observer to combine the two states together, but the basic idea should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this example sets up two state variables, one to determine if the mouse has entered or exited the button and one which determines if the timer has completed or not.

If these two conditions are `true`, then the border is set.

This means that the border of the `react` button WON'T be changed if the mouse is NOT over the `trigger` button when the timer runs out, but if the user moves back into the button, it will be changed.  It will also be changed in the mouse is over the `trigger` button AND the timer runs out

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public static final Border PANEL_BORDER = new LineBorder(Color.red, 12);

        private boolean mouseInTheHouse = false;
        private boolean timedOut = false;

        private JButton react;
        private JButton trigger;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.ipadx = 200;
            gbc.ipady = 60;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            react = new JButton("React");
            trigger = new JButton("Trigger");

            add(react, gbc);
            add(trigger, gbc);

            trigger.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseInTheHouse = true;
                    stateChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseInTheHouse = false;
                }

            });
            Timer timer = new Timer(4000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    timedOut = true;
                    System.out.println("!!");
                    stateChanged();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void stateChanged() {
            if (mouseInTheHouse && timedOut) {
                react.setBorder(PANEL_BORDER);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Note, that I've not setup a condition for what should happen when the mouse leaves the `trigger` button, but I assume you'd reset the border.

> I see. I have an additional question. What if I had 10 trigger buttons (top of the panel) and 10 react button (bottom of the panel)? The condition is: If I have my mouse over one of the trigger button, then the corresponding react button of the same position plus the react button to the right side of that react button will have borders. How do I detect that without looping through my button List and detecting mouseInHouse?

Basically, distill the idea down to it's most common level.  You have two buttons, a `Timer`, `MouseListener` and two state variables.  Wrap these up into a common class which you can then reuse.

```
public class ButtonStateManager {

    private boolean mouseInTheHouse = false;
    private boolean timedOut = false;

    private JButton trigger;
    private JButton react;

    private Timer timer;

    public ButtonStateManager(JButton trigger, JButton react, int timeOut) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
        this.react = react;

        trigger.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseInTheHouse = true;
                stateChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseInTheHouse = false;
            }

        });

        Timer timer = new Timer(timeOut, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timedOut = true;
                stateChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void stateChanged() {
        if (mouseInTheHouse && timedOut) {
            react.setBorder(TestPane.PANEL_BORDER);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, this assumes there's a relationship between the two buttons.

Comment: I see. I have an additional question. What if I had 10 trigger buttons (top of the panel) and 10 react button (bottom of the panel)? The condition is: If I have my mouse over one of the trigger button, then the corresponding react button of the same position plus the react button to the right side of that react button will have borders. How do I detect that without looping through my button List and detecting mouseInHouse?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I used a MouseInfo to get the location, used the component method findComponentAt() and checked the instance of it, and then called mouseEnter. Thank you though!

Comment: The basic idea would be to wrap the MouseAdpter and ActionListener into a single reusable class. This could then be used to manage the states

Answer (score 0):

If your mouse is on the `trigger` button, and then `MouseListener` is added to the button, it cannot capture the previously happened event of entering the `trigger` button's area.

If you insist on showing the border when your mouse is on the `trigger` button without getting off and on it again, you should call the `mouseEnter` method manually after you add the `mouseListener` to it:

(before that you should pass the `final JFrame frame` to your `countDown` method)

```
if(seconds == 0){
      timer.cancel(); 
      trigger.addMouseListener(mL);
      Point mousePosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
      Rectangle triggerRect = trigger.getBounds();
      Rectangle frameRect = frame.getBounds();
      Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(triggerRect.x + frameRect.x, triggerRect.y + frameRect.y, triggerRect.width, triggerRect.height);
      if(newRect.contains(mousePosition)) {
          mL.mouseEntered(new MouseEvent(trigger, 0, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1, 0, 0, 0, false));
      }
      return;
}
```

But as MadProgrammer mentioned your question is not clear by saying *"I'm trying to have the react button appear with a border after the timer has ended".*

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens if the mouse isn't actually over the button?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Very good point to consider! I should check if the mouse is actually in the button's area and then call the `mouseEntered` method. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that two, but I think there's a simpler way ;)

Comment: Actually @STaefi, this is a very good solution. I'm trying to apply it to my situation with 10 trigger buttons and 10 react buttons without looping, so it's not as efficient to how I want to use it. I would prefer to skip the looping.

Comment: @PhongVo yes event or action listeners are some methods most likely designed as `public` methods in some interfaces which can be called similar to other methods. Actually the mechanism of registering listeners which their nethods are called in some situations or due to an action is some method calls under the hood.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: liked your way and it deserves a +1 ;-)